# Unable to run svelte/tailwind project

Tags: svelte, tailwind-css

I created a svelte project and setup tailwindui, when I try to launch the project I get this error:

```
postcss.config.js:1
[1] import tailwind from 'tailwindcss'
[1] ^^^^^^
[1]
[1] SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I also get this error:

```
[0] [!] (plugin svelte) ParseError: Unexpected character '@'
[0] src/App.svelte
[0] 1: <script>
[0] 2:   @tailwind base;
[0]      ^
[0] 3:   @tailwind components;
[0] 4:   @tailwind utilities;
[0] ParseError: Unexpected character '@
```

This is my postcss.config.css file:

```
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
import nesting from 'postcss-nesting'

export default  {
    syntax: 'postcss-scss',
    plugins: [
        nesting(),
        tailwind(),
        autoprefixer(),
        
    ],
};
};
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your postcss.config.js should look like this as shown in the [tailwindcss docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

To fix the second error you have to put all tailwindcss imports in a style tag like this:

```html
<style>
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've set up svelte + tailwind a couple times already, the tailwindcss docs on it is quite simple to follow and works like a charm [Install tailwind css with svelte](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34554281)

Comment: Following the tailwind set up guide for svelte as of july '23 doesn't work. Very frustrating, as the project is the svelte skeleton, and no alterations have yet been made. Linking to the docs that we all have read doesn't provide help.

Comment: @RinandLen this was my experience as well.  I've tried vite and rollup tutorials and none of them work.